# Maximo erData XML

Tags: maximo, inbound

I have an enterprise service with both a user exit class and an XSL map.  Is there a way to write to the logs the actual XML of erData (StructureData object) used in the exit class?  I have tried erData.toString(), but that writes

```
[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <fw:root [Namespace: http://www.ibm.com/maximo]/>]]
```

to the log, not the XML.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDocs for Maximo 7.6](https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/), StructureData.getData() will return an instance of org.jdom.Document, on which, according to the [JavaDocs for JDOM 1](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Document.html), you should be able to call toString() to return "a String representation of the Document, suitable for debugging."

Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

`erData.getDataAsString()` will do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.